# Как построить диаграмму Вороного по отрезкам?

Tags: python, диаграммы

Помогите, пожалуйста, с кодом!

Как построить диаграмму Вороного по отрезкам?
Сейчас строит только по точкам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас такой код:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr_wells = np.loadtxt('11.txt', dtype='str')
name_well_column = 0
x1_coordinate_column = 1
y1_coordinate_column = 2

arr_x1_well = np.array(arr_wells[:, x1_coordinate_column], dtype='float')
arr_y1_well = np.array(arr_wells[:, y1_coordinate_column], dtype='float')

points = np.array([arr_x1_well, arr_y1_well]).transpose()

vor = Voronoi(points)
print(vor.vertices)

fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

Файл 11.txt:

```
1   40000   90580
2   40650   91050
3   40170   90020
4   40700   90480
5   41400   91020
6   41050   90180
7   41650   90540
8   42350   90940
9   41820   90210
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Приложите содержимое `11.txt` текстом к вопросу (оно вроде небольшое должно быть). 2) Объясните, что такое "по точкам" и "по отрезкам" имеется в виду.

Comment: 1. Содержимое приложила (это просто координаты x и y точек). 
2. По отрезкам имеется ввиду если бы у каждого элемента были координаты x1, y1, x2, y2, т.е. начальная точка и конечная точка, соединенные в отрезок

Comment: У меня пока нет времени, но так вопрос стал гораздо лучше оформлен, ваш код можно запустить у себя с вашими данными и что-то попробовать. Может кто-то возьмётся помочь.

Comment: Диаграмма Вороного множества отрезков может содержать невыпуклые ячейки с параболами на границе. Если вы готовы бороться с этим монстром, я поищу работы посвящённые его быстрому построению.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104631/create-voronoi-diagram-from-line-segments

Comment: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.2920&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Откуда такая задача?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy у меня не получается подключить библиотеку pyvoronoi. Я новичок в этом деле, Вы можете подсказать как можно адаптировать мой код?

Comment: Опишите ваши трудности с pyvoronoy отдельным вопросом. Включите туда версию ОС, Питона, ваши шаги по установке и пример программы, которая не работает (или какая ошибка при установке, если ошибка там).